# is it allowed to clear the "designed by freepik.com" from the vectors?

Tags: legal

it is legal to modify freepik vectors, does this mean that it is legal to delete the text written "designed by freepik.com" on the vectors? Second question: is it legal to use freepik vectors in a youtube group (6 youtubers cooporating together in the same youtube channel)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Freepik.com requires you link back to the author when you're on the free plan:

**Free Plan**

- 33,500+ vectors
- 2,000+ new vectors every month
- Requires a link back to credit the author
- 2 steps download
- Limit of 60 downloads / day

Paid plans do not require this. More info [here](https://profile.freepik.com/plans)

---

You **can** however use it anyway you like, so I don't see a problem with using it in a YT group.